# How can I find the owner of a telegram bot?

Tags: bots, telegram

I have joined to a telegram bot, but I don't know the owner of that. Is it possible to find the owner of a telegram bot?

Comment: I don't think so. Identity of bot's owner/creator completely irrelevant to bot's functionality.

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible to see the owner of a Telegram Bot according to [Telegram MTProto protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto).
Probably only [Bot Support](https://t.me/BotSupport) and [Telegram Abuse](https://telegram.org/faq#q-there-39s-illegal-content-on-telegram-how-do-i-take-it-down) has access to this informations.

**If you want to report a malicious bot you can send a mail to Telegram Abuse:** abuse@telegram.org